# Building a webapp with Javascript MVC and no server side technologies. What to use?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, air, adobe, local-storage

Looking at using a Javascript MVC framework to build a web app (without using any server side technologies) which i can then eventually port to iOS/Android or Adobe Air for Desktop machines.

What is the best framework to use? Found a few [links here](http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed/) which detailed a few good examples, but nothing there noted how i should be storing data (using JSON flatfiles, db files etc)

Can anyone let me know which of these frameworks allow for this and any relevant tutorials/links i should be reading.

Looking at in the end creating an Air app for fellow D&D players to use for their character sheets (just for my group of D&D players), obviously having the data stored persistently on their machines.

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember.js looks like the best choice for a MVC framework.

When it comes to data storage, you have a few built-in options: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage. These have their own pros/cons and have limited support.

I don't know of any frameworks that handle this, but it would be possible to abstract this within your models:

```
var pf = new PlayerFactory;
pf.getById('player-id');
```

then

```
function PlayerFactory()
{
  this.getById = function(playerId)
  {
    var key = 'player-'+playerId;
    if (localStorage.get(key) {
      var p = new Player();
      p.setAttributes(localStorage.get(key);
      return p;
    }
    return false;
  } 

  return this;
}
```

Comment: just noticed a typo in that

`function PlayerFactory()
{
  this.getById = function(playerId)
  {
    var key = 'player-'+playerId;
    if (localStorage.get(key)) {
      var p = new Player();
      p.setAttributes(localStorage.get(key);
      return p;
    }
    return false;
  } 

  return this;
}`

there was a bracket missing